# HTTP Compression on IIS 6.0 (Windows Server 2003)

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, performance, http, compression

There are many things you have to do/consider when you want to enable HTTP compression on IIS 6.0 (Windows Server 2003).

Can somebody please provide a comprehensive list of the actions you have to take in order to enable HTTP compression properly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- [HTTP COMPRESSION in IIS 6 and IIS 7 using Service Account](http://blogs.msdn.com/vivekkum/archive/2009/02/18/http-compression-in-iis-6-and-iis-7-using-service-account.aspx)
- TechNet - [Enabling HTTP Compression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782942%28WS.10%29.aspx)
- [IIS Compression in IIS6.0](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2004/01/12/57916.aspx)
- [How to enable HTTP compression (IIS6)](http://www.kavinda.net/2007/02/17/how-to-enable-http-compression-iis6.html)
- [HTTP Compression and IIS 6.0](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000059.html)
- [IIS 6 Compression - quickest and effective way to do it for ASP.NET compression](http://msmvps.com/blogs/omar/archive/2006/08/10/iis-6-compression-quickest-and-effective-way-to-do-it-for-asp-net-compression.aspx)

**UPDATE**:

To verify that compression works, you could use Firefox with Firebug and YSlow plugins, they will show compression status for each component (html, javascript, css).

Also, in order to test each compression method (gzip/deflate) you could alter the "**network.http.accept-encoding**" preference in Firefox (default value is "**gzip,deflate**")

Comment: you might also want to check http://blogs.msdn.com/vivekkum/archive/2009/02/18/http-compression-in-iis-6-and-iis-7-using-service-account.aspx if you have appPool configured to run under a different account.

Answer (score 3):

Does anyone know how you TEST if your IIS6 server is sending zipped content?

Is there a "test your website" site out there that can tell you??

Can you use Firefox to tell you (firebug or some other plug in?)

**[UPDATE]**

Using YSlow with FireBug.  Click on the "components" tab and it shows raw and gzipped sizes.

Comment: YOu can use the Firefox Firebug extension (network tab). It shows you the details of the server's response. If you're using a proxy be sure the proxy doesn't "swallow" the compression.

Comment: Or use Fiddler (www.fiddlertool.com) for IE.

Comment: check my updated answer above

Answer (score 1):

I played around with getting this set-up on our server (IIS 6) and while enabling it was fairly simple, it didn't give us as much control over it as I needed. I ended up purchasing [httpZip from port80 Software](http://www.port80software.com/products/httpzip/). It made it trivial to enable and configure it. It looks like IIS 7 is much better about this.

Answer (score 1):

I used **[this walkthrough](http://www.salutony.com/Lists/KB/DispForm.aspx?ID=9)** to setup HTTP Compression (gzip and deflate) on IIS 6. I used **[this metabase.xml example](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/08/http-compression-and-iis-6-0.html)** to tweak my configuration for best results.